# Android Orientation in Titanium Alloy

Tags: javascript, android, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I would like my app to allow both portrait and landscape modes in Android but most options i found don't seem to work or possibly i'm not implementing them correctly.

I've tried setting up the code from this example with no luck:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Orientation

This is my manifest code for Android in my tiapp.xml

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>         
        <!-- This removes the action ot title bar in Android. -->
        <application android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Comment: i have zero `uses-permission`  nodes in my tiapp, and portrait and landscape was functioning from the start. might check your device

Comment: I think the permissions are for the app store to let the user know what the app has access to. Is there some code i need to add to the manifest to make it rotate fullsensor.

Answer (score 0):

it's my **`tiapp.xml`** file about android config and the window that will only show a status bar:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <manifest>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:label="Test" android:name="TestApplication" android:debuggable="false" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    </application>
  </manifest>
</android>
```

Comment: I'll try this out. Thanks